# How to change CSS in Magento

Tags: css, magento

Need to change the styles of a category in Magento, I don't have access to the css directly so I want to change it with the CMS.

I've tried calling the sheet styles through head but it doesn't works.

Any help please?

Comment: Why don't you have access to the css directly? Are you a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're a client and have no access to the CSS file, then I suppose the only thing you can do is use Magento's **before_head_end** hook and place some arbitrary styles in the head to try and override the other stylesheet.

Proceed to Admin > System > Configuration > General > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts and use the

```
<style>
    .my-style {} 
<\style>
```

tags to start styling. 
Let me know if you have any trouble.